# What is the difference between static_rnn and dynamic_rnn?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, what is the difference between `tf.nn.static_rnn` and `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, and when to use them?

Both take a `sequence_length` argument that adapts the computation to the actual length of the input; it is not as if `static_rnn` is limited to fixed-size inputs, right?

`dynamic_rnn` has the following extra arguments:

- `parallel_iterations`
- `swap_memory`
- `time_major`

But I suppose these are only minor differences.

So what is the main difference between `tf.nn.static_rnn` and `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` and when should we use one over the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is still a useful resource (despite being written a couple years ago):
http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/

In it, Denny Britz has the following comment on the static/dynamic issue:

**Static**

> Internally, `tf.nn.rnn` creates an unrolled graph for a fixed RNN length. That means, if you call `tf.nn.rnn` with inputs having 200 time steps you are creating a static graph with 200 RNN steps. First, graph creation is slow. Second, you’re unable to pass in longer sequences (> 200) than you’ve originally specified.

**Dynamic**

> `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` solves this. It uses a `tf.While` loop to dynamically construct the graph when it is executed. That means graph creation is faster and you can feed batches of variable size.

In general he concludes that there is no real benefit in using `tf.nn.static_rnn` and that for most cases you'll want to resort to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`

For what it's worth, I've had the same experience myself.

Comment: Note that second order gradients are not supported for `tf.while` at the moment, thus if you need that, you need to use `tf.nn.static_rnn`.